# Javascript not cleaning up old images in browser

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, websocket

I have an HTML page that takes base64 image data from a WebSocket and then displays it to the user. The image is periodically changed (a new base64 image is pushed over the socket), so a new image must be decoded and then displayed to the user.

My current problem is that after the image is updated, it appears that the previous image(s) are never removed from the browser's memory. If I take a look at Chrome's resources page, I can see all of the images still sitting in the browser memory. If the image files are large enough and change rapidly enough, the browser's memory will fill to the point where it will crash.

Any idea on how this can be resolved? I've pasted a snippet of the code below.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Presenter</title>

<style>
 html,body{font:normal 0.9em arial,helvetica;text-align:center;}
#dynamicImage { margin:0px auto; }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
function handleMessage(data) {
    switch(data.type) {
        case 'imageUpdate':         
            // replace the image            
            $('#dynamicImage').attr({
                'src': "data:image/jpeg;base64," + data.image,
            }); 
            break;
    }
}
</script>
</head>

<body>  
 <div id="dynamicImageWrapper">
    <img id="dynamicImage" src="./WhitePixel45w.jpg" />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to quickly get around this - the first relies on you making your server send out images with a no-cache or cache expiration header in the past. That way reloading the image always reloads it in cache, too, rather than just fetching it from cache without checking for a newer version the server.

The other option requires far less work: instead of getting image "image.jpg", get image "image.jpg?t=", because as far as the browser is concerned this is a new URL every time.

The tradeoff is cache flooding - the first approach is clean, but requires fiddling on your server, and may even require you to write an image serving script in a server-side language whose sole responsibility it is to send an image with the "nocache" or "cache expiry in the past" header text set. The second approach is immediately implementatble and very, very easy, but it may also fill up a user's cache if this image is updated many times while the user is on the page.

Comment: I'm confused as to why you suggested an answer which involves cache flooding, as it seems that is exactly what my initial problem is. I would actually prefer to have one image (or perhaps the past 5 or 10 images) cached, so that if the existing cached image is equal to the new image, the image does not need to be reloaded. Is this possible?

Comment: The only way to make this happen is to serve the image with a no-cache or cache expiration time in the past, so that the next time you fetch it, the original cached copy is overwritten.  However, be aware that if you turn on resource tracking, normal cache rules no longer apply: because you told it to do resource tracking, even with no-cache it will show this resource because you indicated you wanted to see everything, including data that may already be overwritten. I'd use an imageservice script for this, something like <img src='getimage.php?image=someimage.jpg"/>